# Which one is greater: O(N^2 * log(N^2)) or O(N^3)?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

I want to find time complexity for the following:

```
int i, j, k; 
for(i = 1; i <= N^2+N^2; i = i + 3)  ***//O(N^2)*** 
{
     for(j = i; j <= N ; j = j + 3)  ***//O(N^3)***
    
     { 
     } 
     
     for(k = 1; k<= N^2 ; k = k * 2)  ***//O(log(N^2)*N^2)***
      
     { 
     } 
}
```

i have resolved it as following, but i am confused whether O(N^2 * log(N^2)) is greater or O(N^3)

Comment: Hint: log(N^2) = 2log(N). Can you answer it now?

Comment: The `j` loop is not O(N), it's O(max(0, N-i)), which is relevant because mostly `i` is larger than `N`, and this loop actually contributes nothing to the overall time complexity.

Comment: O(log(n^x)) < O(n)

Answer (score 2):

This is a very sneaky piece of code whose runtime is a bit more nuanced than I expected it to be. Here's what you have:

```
int i, j, k; 
for(i = 1; i <= N^2+N^2; i = i + 3)
{
     for(j = i; j <= N ; j = j + 3)
     { 
     } 

     for(k = 1; k<= N^2 ; k = k * 2)
     { 
     } 
}
```

@Paul Hankin made the important observation that, once `i` gets sufficiently large, that first loop never executes. As a result, to analyze this loop, we'll need to consider two cases: one where the top loop executes some number of iterations, and one where it doesn't.

To do this, notice that your code is essentially equivalent to the following, where I've broken the outer loop apart into two smaller loops:

```
int i, j, k; 
for(i = 1; i <= N; i = i + 3)
{
     for(j = i; j <= N ; j = j + 3)
     { 
     } 

     for(k = 1; k<= N^2 ; k = k * 2)
     { 
     } 
} 

for(i = N+1; i <= N^2+N^2; i = i + 3)
{
     for(k = 1; k<= N^2 ; k = k * 2)
     { 
     } 
}
```

With that taken care of, let's look at these loops independently. As usual, we'll use the maxim

> When in doubt, work inside out!

and start replacing deeper loops with statements indicating how much work they do. Let's begin with the loop that counts from 1 up to N<sup>2</sup> by repeatedly doubling. That loop will run roughly log N<sup>2</sup> = 2 log N = Θ(log n) times, so we get this:

```
int i, j, k; 
for(i = 1; i <= N; i = i + 3)
{
     for(j = i; j <= N ; j = j + 3)
     { 
     } 

     do Θ(log N) work;
} 

for(i = N+1; i <= N^2+N^2; i = i + 3)
{
     do Θ(log N) work;
}
```

Similarly, the loop that counts from i up to N does Θ(N - i) work, so we get this:

```
int i, j, k; 
for(i = 1; i <= N; i = i + 3)
{
     do Θ(N - i) work;
     do Θ(log N) work;
} 

for(i = N+1; i <= N^2+N^2; i = i + 3)
{
     do Θ(log N) work;
}
```

Now, focus on the second of those two loops. That second loop runs Θ(N<sup>2</sup>) times (since (2N<sup>2</sup> - N) / 3 = Θ(N<sup>2</sup>)), doing O(log N) work each time, so it does Θ(N<sup>2</sup> log N) total work:

```
int i, j, k; 
for(i = 1; i <= N; i = i + 3)
{
     do Θ(N - i) work;
     do Θ(log N) work;
} 

do Θ(N^2 log N) work;
```

Now we have that first loop. We need to sum up (N - i + log N) over i = 1, 4, 7, 10, 13, etc. The sum of N - i from i = 1, 4, 7, 10, ..., N works out to Θ(N<sup>2</sup>), and one way to see this is to use this picture to see that this ends up roughly being the area (something that grows quadratically) of a triangle:

```
 *
 ****
 *******
 **********
 *************
```

The sum of log N running Θ(N) times works out to Θ(N log N) total work, so we end up with this loop requiring Θ(N<sup>2</sup>) time because N<sup>2</sup> dominates N log N. Therefore, we have

```
do Θ(N^2) work;
do Θ(N^2 log N) work;
```

so the overall runtime is **Θ(N<sup>2</sup> log N)**.

Returning to the question you asked, though: how does Θ(N<sup>3</sup>) compare against Θ(N<sup>2</sup> log N)? If we cancel out the N<sup>2</sup> terms that they share, we're left with the question of how N compares against log N. We know that log N grows much, much more slowly than N, and so N<sup>2</sup> log N = o(N<sup>3</sup>).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try to make a limit of these two expression:

```
L = lim_{N \to \infty} N^3/(N^2 log(N^2)) = lim_{N \to \infty} N/log(N^2)
```

As you can find the hint in comments, `log(N^2) = 2 log(N)`. Now we have:

```
L = 1/2 lim_{N \to \infty} N/log(N)
```

As the growth of `N` is more than `log(N)`, we can conclude that `L = \infty`. Hence, The given algorithm is `O(N^3)`.